# Where are all the robots near the end of Elysium?

Tags: elysium

At the end of Elysium

> Max, Kruger and others crash land on Elysium. Moments later, ships arrive with guard robots, charged with arresting the occupants of the ship.

However, from that moment until the final scene where

> Elysium's computer reboots and Spider tells Patel that all the people of Earth are now citizens of Elysium

there are no robots to be seen.

Is there any in-universe explanation for the sudden disappearance of the robots and

> Elysium's reliance on Kruger and his men

or is it simply a gaping plot hole?

Answer (score 1):

When Max and the others were arrested and taken to Delacourt, the guard robots would have left to their stations outside the headquarters. There would be no reason for them to be stationed inside the headquarters as they only arrest those who are **not** citizens of Elysium, and those that aren't were already being dealt with.

Also, nobody would have expected there to be chaos: with everyone running around and/or getting killed as something like this never happened before (smugglers have landed before but I don't think anyone had broken into the headquarters). Therefore, there might not have been a protocol for the robots to come inside and deal with all the shooting (as again, **Kruger and his men would have been seen as citizens**) and if there was, nobody alerted the robots because of all that was happening and their go-to-response was to seek safety.

*Speculation ofcourse :)*

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that the robots were instructed (if I remember correctly) to detain everyone in the ship.